# Synonyms break favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-watching

Possibly related to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75154/ignored-tags-doesnt-handle-synonyms.

I've had `c++0x` favorited for a long time. Now that it's been made a synonym of `c++11` (I think this was done backwards, [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) is no more "Official" than C++0x and C++0x has much more widespread use), it no longer brings me questions related to ISO/IEC 14882:2011, AKA C++0x, AKA C++11.

Synonym translation needs to be applied to favorited tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignored tags doesn't handle synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75154/ignored-tags-doesnt-handle-synonyms)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It is similar, which I why I linked to the other question, but I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: There should be just a report, instead of two. Apart referring to favorite tags or ignored tags, the bug report is the same: tags that are synonyms of a tag you added to one of those lists should be considered.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: You're misunderstanding the problem.  The problem is not synonyms of my favorite tag, it's that my tag has been demoted to being a synonym of another tag.  If my tag were the master, the synonym system would force all questions to carry it, and it would work correctly.  But the newer tag is the master, so NO questions carry my tag anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag merges from now on will remap both favorite and ignored tags.

If you ignore `bacon` and we merge `bacon` into `bacontastic` you will now ignore `bacontastic`

Comment: Why would anyone in their right mind ignore bacon?